# QString degree symbol

Tags: qt, special-characters, qstring

I wonder what is the best and cleanest solution to write a degree symbol in a translation.

I had `tr( "Snap to 90%1 angles" ).arg( QString::fromUtf8( "°" ) )` but this is not really nice.

I tried without success: `tr( "Snap to 90° angles" )`

I use this in a QAction: `mCommonAngleAction = new QAction( tr( "Snap to 90° angles" ), menu );`

Here is the result:

[image]

Do you have a good solution?

Comment: May help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18758252/how-to-print-degree-symbol-on-the-window-using-qt5qtquick-2-1-and-above

Comment: qt version? if qt5 check this out: [trUtf8](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject-obsolete.html#trUtf8).

Comment: thanks, but I'm on Qt4, and trUtf8 is obsolete...

Answer (score 6):

The string you want to print depends quite a lot on where you want to print it. So where do you want to print `Snap to 90° angles`?

If you want to set a `QLabel` text to `Snap to 90° angles` a piece of code like `label->setText(tr("Snap to 90° angles"));` works just fine.

If you want to print it to console it depends on the console. If the console doesn't support `UTF-8`, unless you set a flag on that console to support `UTF-8` characters, you're out of luck.

In a QMainWindow constructor, using the code

```
ui->menubar->actions().first()->setText(QObject::tr("Snap to 90° angless"));
```

generates:

[image]

Comment: Can you show us the code? I tried using it on a `QAction` and for me it worked. See the edits above...

Comment: Thanks a lot for precising. I have edited the question. As you notice, this is on linux.

Comment: @DenisRouzaud Have you considered `tr(QString::fromUtf8("Snap to 90° angless"))`?

Comment: Thanks luliu, I hoped for a shorter version, but that is a solution yes.